How to set a image in the header via fancyhdr?
I am veeery new to LaTeX but I am encountering a very weird issue, because I need to have the header, on only the first page, as shown in the screenshot. And the Univeristy provided a rectangular image (link here), and I figured it would be very easy to just use \includegraphics, but it seems very hard to do it in a clean way, and trying to copy-paste code seems to give me a dirty code that I would rather not have. Sadly the fancyhdr manual doesn't show any example of putting an image into the header, so I don't know where to look.


Welcome to TeX.SX!. Usually it is not a problem to use \includegraphics in the header definition with fancyhdr and there are already questions about. So can you please add a minimal working example that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

Here is an example I have in my collection of fancyhdr solutions.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[headheight=45pt, includehead]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{makecell}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\newcommand{\headfont}{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{%
  \mbox{\makecell[cl]{\includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image}}}
    \headfont
    \makecell[cl]{%
      Journal on Teaching Engineering, 1:1 (2015) 5-15 \\
      ISSN XXX-XXXX \\
      DOI: \href{https://doi.org/10.24840/2183-6493\_00X.00X\_00XX}{10.24840/2183-6493\_001.001\_0011}
    }}
    
  \fancyhead[R]{\headfont
    \makecell[cr]{%
      Received: XX December, XXX \\
      Revised: XX December, XXX \\
      Published: XX December, XXXX
    }}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\headfont\textbf{\thepage}}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}



I ended up solving the main issue, via reading a lot about fancyhdr and makecell/minipage.
I ended up with a very pleasing result, but I feel the code is somewhat dirty and there may be better solutions (especially for multiple lines in minipages and in tables)
\documentclass{article}

% Lingua
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

% Pagina e margini
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

% Spacing
\linespread{1.15}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% Fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}[
Extension={.otf},
Path=./Fonts/,
UprightFont={*},
BoldFont={*-SemiBold},
ItalicFont={*-Italic},
BoldItalicFont={*-SemiBoldItalic}]

% Colors
\definecolor{rossovanvitelli}{rgb}{0.63529,0.11373,0.13333}

\setsansfont{Titillium}[
Extension={.otf},
Path=./Fonts/,
UprightFont={*},
BoldFont={*-SemiBold},
ItalicFont={*-Italic},
BoldItalicFont={*-SemiBoldItalic}]

% Header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{110pt}
    %\fancyhead[R]{} 
\fancyhead[L]{
\color{rossovanvitelli}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \vspace*{5pt}
        \includegraphics*[width=160pt]{Logo-Unicampania.pdf}% non c'è l'ambiente figure.
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}
        \makecell[tl]{\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont{Scuola di Medicina e}\\\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont{Chirurgia}} & 
        \makecell[tl]{\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont{Dipartimento di}\\\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont{Scienze Mediche e}\\\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont{Chirurgiche Avanzate}}
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
    }

% Infos
\title{Tesi}
\author{Tu}
\date{April 2024}

% Inizio 
% -------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\vspace*{10em}

\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont
\textit{Corso di Laurea Magistrale in}

\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont
\textbf{Medicina e Chirurgia - Sede di Caserta}

\vspace*{5em}

{
\sffamily
\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}
\textbf{Tesi di Laurea Sperimentale/Compilativa in (indicare Materia e SSD)}

\vspace*{0.25em}

\fontsize{23pt}{23pt}
\text{Titolo della tesi}

\fontsize{14}{14}
\selectfont{Sottotitolo}
}

\vspace*{15em}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.21\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
\makecell[l]{Candidato \\ \fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont\textit{Tizio Caio} \\ Matr. A2300XXX} & ~ & \makecell[l]{Relatore \\ \fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont\textit{Prof.} \\ \fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont\textit{Tizio Caio}} & A.A. 2024/2025
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}



I had the same issue with my uni essays, where I had to put the logo in the right corner on the first page and it was a pain.
I foud the background package to be the most helpful. So you're technically not defining the header, but that means you don't have to worry about adjusting marigins, fitting graphics etc.
In the line \usepackage[pages=some, placement=top]{background} the fact that you specify pages=some means that this background picture will not be inserted untill you call \BgThispage- then it will be inserted on that page, and that page only.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pages=some, placement=top]{background}
\usepackage[hmargin = 1.0in, vmargin = 1.25in]{geometry} % change marigin sizes here
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=1,
  contents={
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{figures and formatting/header.png}}}

% some text
\section{Introduction}
\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage
\section{Methods}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}

Here is the output: 

Welcome to TeX.SE!
